# Is there a way to make a qgis project only editable by me

Tags: qgis, editing

In QGIS, currently Lisboa 1.8.0 is there a way to make it only editable by me.  I want to set up projects for each client on the network, so when all the files are on the network and the program and project are saved on the network that everyone can view it and interogate it but only I can edit layers, add new layers, draw on it, etc etc.

I dont know if this is in the right section or if it is answerable.

I may need to clarify this point i think.

Comment: Might be worth considering the "embed layers" functionality. Embedded layers are read-only.

Comment: is there a tutorial on how to work this function anywhere off the top of your head?

Comment: Try it. It's very straight-forward.

Comment: embarrassed to say nothing happened. i can still edit and if i just start a blank map and click it nothing comes up. I will endeavour.

Comment: oh wait got it!

Comment: Ok got the layers importing perfect.  But the proplem persists that if i make these open to everyone then it will be allowing them to edit the files.  I need to be the only one who can edit.

Comment: This seems like a classic operating system solution.  Give yourself rights to edit the project file/folder and give everyone else read only rights.